# Hive Using Collect Aggregation

Tags: hadoop, hive, collect

I wanted to remove duplicate values from a hive table
so i am using this query

```
INSERT INTO TABLE final_table 
 select 
   A,
   B,
   collect(coalesce(C,0))[0],
   collect(coalesce(D,0))[0],
   collect(coalesce(E,0))[0],
   collect(coalesce(F,0))[0],
   collect(coalesce(G,0))[0]
 from 
   temp_table
 group by 
   A,B ;
```

as `A,B` are primary keys.

But in the result I am still getting duplicate values.
Is there some issue with query?

Answer (score 0):

Try either using the 'collect_set' UDF, or collect into a map, and use 'map_keys' to get the keys from the map.